# Simple Derivative

Tags: calculus

I am wanting trying to remember how to solve a derivative of this nature:

$$ \frac{dM}{dt} =  rM(t)$$
$$ dM = rM(t)dt $$

Solving when t = 0 equals 1 we can get the solution as

$$ M(t)= M(0)e^{rt} $$

Comment: this method is called seperation of variables,where  you are moving one variable on one side,another  variable on another side and integrate seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

divide both side by  $M(t)$,we get $dM/M(t)=rdt$  now know that integral of $1/t$ is $ln(t)$,can you follow from this?

EDit:

if we integrate we get $ln(M(t))=rt+c$  or  $M(t)=e^{r*t+c}$

now let us represent $e^{r*t+c}=e^{r*t}*e^{c}$;if we denote  $e^c=C$,we get

M(t)=$e^{r*t+c}=C*e^{r*t}$

from there $M(0)=C=1$

Comment: Thank you. I knew I was forgetting something simple.

Comment: you are welcome,good lucks

Comment: the M(0) just comes form $$ M(t) = ce^{rt} $$ I am a little confused about how that is defined as the C just solves to one.

Comment: yes exactly,look  $e^{r*t+c}=e^{r*t}*e^{c}$,now let us denote $e^{c}$ by big $C$,because $e^{c}$ is constant

Comment: Hahaha brain fart. Thank you.

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: wish everything best

Answer (score 2):

Separation of variables is the way to go. Your solution is correct.

We have:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{M}~dM = r \int dt$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer too.

Comment: @amWhy: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11640/why-dont-people-vote-for-posts-any-more